# Height calculation differences between IE7 and Firefox/Safari

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css

this is driving me crazy...might be something very simple and I just need another set of eyes to look at it...

I have this in my CSS:

```
#recipient {
width: 31%;
text-align: center;
min-height: 335px;
float: right;   
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
border: 2px solid black;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
padding: 11px 0;
font-size: 0.875em;
}
```

and call it here in my HTML:

```
<div id="recipient">
<h3>Meet the 2010 Recipient!</h3>
<a href="recipient.html"><img src="images/2010_headshot.jpg" alt="foo" /></a>
</div>
```

Pretty simple, right? In Firefox it renders about 20px longer in height than IE7 (I can tell by where the bottom of this div hits next to other elements on the page). I am running in standards mode, and have looked at the Firefox version in Firebug and the IE version with Firebug Light and the IE Dev Toolbar -- don't see anything weird in either... the top of the div starts in the right spot, so it doesn't look like the margin collapsing...

If I manually add padding/height to the CSS, I can get IE7 to line it up at the right height, but then the div in Firefox is too long! It's not a critical part of the design, but it's bugging the sh!t out of me!!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using (almost) Standards mode?

Comment: Yes, I am...tested using document.compatMode with a result of CSS1Compat

Comment: it would be nice if you showed a test-case with this issue , or provide URL to the problematic site

Comment: Watch out --IE often uses a slightly different box model than the rest of the known universe.

Comment: Let me try the solution below, if that doesn't work I'll throw a test case up -thanks

Comment: Ugg - so, turns out I'm an idiot. After trying to create a test case I could not replicate the issue, and trial/error revealed this was an issue caused by a different area of the site. I should have tried to replicate with clean HTML/CSS before posting. What is proper SO etiquette here? Delete the Q? Give the answer to clairesuzy below for providing helpful information which could have solved the issue if this had actually been the problem I faced? Thanks for the comments everyone, sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's IE and the different way it's handling the default `h3` margins  inside a floated element

usually this can be fixed by giving the offending element (any element which has default margins!) **explicit** margins, but in this case it's not working because of the top padding of the container ?

The best fix I can come up with is to remove the top padding from the `#recipient` div and explicit;y make the top/bottom margins on the `h3` *11px*, this makes for nice even spaces through the effect (btw this extra bit only happens if the div is taller than the min height) - here's some working code -  I also put a background color on the `h3` which if you do in your code will show the 15px or so extra gap..

**CSS:**

```
#recipient {
width: 31%;
text-align: center;
min-height: 335px;
float: right;   
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
border: 2px solid black;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 0.875em;
padding-bottom: 11px; /* bottom padding only */
}

h3 {
 margin: 11px 0; /* explicitly set these */
 background: #fcf;
}
```

**HTML:** (with placeholder image for testing)

```
<div id="recipient">
  <h3>Meet the 2010 Recipient!</h3>
  <a href="recipient.html"><img src="http://placekitten.com/350/200/" alt="foo" /></a>
</div>
```